# global-auto-revert-mode doesn't seem to work?

Tags: minor-mode, revert-buffer, auto-revert-mode

My init file includes

```
(setq global-auto-revert-mode t)
```

and I can confirm it's true with C-h v. But I still have to manually revert all my files with revert-buffer whenever I change git branches. I even get as far as trying to save and getting the "file changed on disk" prompt. Any suggestions for how to debug this?

Comment: Try putting this in your init instead: `(global-auto-revert-mode 1)`

Comment: @kaushalmodi no luck (I would have been really surprised)

Comment: Could it be a matter with `auto-revert-interval`? I use it and it works for me, excepting files over tramp.

Comment: Looks like a bug that crept in in 24.5 and 25.0. @SwarnenduBiswas are you on emacs 24.4?

Comment: @djechlin I verified using emacs -Q sessions that auto revert mode does not work on emacs 24.5 and 25.0 but works fine on 24.4. What version are you on?

Comment: @kaushalmodi I recently upgraded to 24.5 about three days back, so my comment is from prior experience with 24.4. Haven't tested auto-revert-mode in 24.5.

Comment: @kaushalmodi 24.3.1.

Comment: @djechlin Can you recreate the problem in an `emacs -Q` session?  Open a file (somefile.txt) in an emacs 24.3 instance with -Q option. Do `M-x global-auto-revert-mode`. From terminal, echo some string (`echo 1234 >> somefile.txt`). Please let us know if somefile.txt still does not auto revert.

Comment: I saw you updated your question with the bug report; but I can see this bug only in emacs 24.5+. I cannot see that on 24.4 and I don't have 24.3 installed (so can't verify that). If you can reproduce this bug on 24.3 in an emacs -Q session, you should file a separate bug report for that.

Comment: @kaushalmodi far simpler problem; see my answer.

Comment: @djechlin But this ended up in discovering an actual bug in emacs 24.5+ :)

Comment: Under OS X, 24.5 `auto-revert` works as intended. However, it looks like it uses the older timer system (`auto-revert-use-notify` is nil) and not the newer file notification system.

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks! I can confirm that auto revert works fine in emacs 24.5 if I set `auto-revert-use-notify` to `nil` (the default value is `t`).

Comment: @kaushalmodi, good, then there is a practical work-around for other OS:es as well. (On a side note -- it's a great feeling that something I wrote back in 1997 is still widely used.)

Comment: @Lindydancer Just to clarify, you have have set `auto-revert-use-notify` to  `nil` on your emacs setup under OSX? Does it work if set to `t`?

Comment: @kaushalmodi, I have not actively set it. I think it's nil since Emacs on OS X doesn't support file notifications. If I set it to `t`, it's reset to `nil` once `global-auto-revert-mode` is enabled. (It looks like `auto-revert-notify-add-watch` use the timer-based system as a fall-back when it fails to add a notification watch.)

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks, glad to see that the outcomes are consistent :) It would have been big pain to debug this; already added this fix to [my init](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/tree/c5e8fc1f7b8eca22e09106d9dae95d176ca7d0bd/setup-files/setup-misc.el#L115-L119).

Comment: It now works with file-notify too on my system. The problem probably was with glib. Surprisingly the issue resolved on killing and restarting the vnc server on which I work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't set the variable using `setq`, you call the function:

```
(global-auto-revert-mode)
```

Comment: I'm wondering how that is different from `(global-auto-revert-mode 1)`. Also if you are adding this to your init, you shouldn't even need that argument. Just `(global-auto-revert-mode)` should suffice. Check out Xah's [blog post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs-tip_mode_on_off_toggle.html) for more info.

Comment: As with any mode defined using `define-global-minor-mode`, the only valid values are numbers, `nil`, and `toggle`. The fact that `t` works is only due to the fact that `prefix-numeric-value` doesn't choke on it and treats it like `1`.

Comment: @Lindydancer Yeah, I'd like djechlin to clarify why passing `1` as argument [did not work](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/global-auto-revert-mode-doesnt-seem-to-work/10971#comment17004_10966).

Comment: @kaushalmodi I was still setq-ing - I thought you were just changing t to a 1, I overlooked the change from setq to calling the function.

Comment: @djechlin Thanks for clarifying. But for the sake of clarify and consistency, it is recommended to pass it an arg `1` or nothing if you want to enable that minor mode from elisp in your init.

Answer (score 16):

**A minor mode is not enabled/disabled by setting a variable.** The minor mode variable should be used to check the "mode enabled" status, not to set the mode state. If its value is `t`, the minor mode is on, else the mode is off.

---

See the below snippets to see how to control any minor mode. *Replace `MINOR-MODE-NAME` with the actual minor mode name you are dealing with (`global-auto-revert-name` as is the case in the question).*

---

### Enabling a minor mode

#### Using elisp

**Directly**

```el
(MINOR-MODE-NAME)
;; or
(MINOR-MODE-NAME 1)
```

**Based on a hook activation**

```el
(add-hook 'SOME-HOOK #'MINOR-MODE-NAME)
```

---

### Disabling a minor mode

#### Using elisp

**Directly**

```el
(MINOR-MODE-NAME 0)
;; or
(MINOR-MODE-NAME -1)
```

**Based on a hook activation**

```el
(add-hook 'SOME-HOOK (lambda () (MINOR-MODE-NAME -1)))
```

---

### Toggling a minor mode

#### Interactively

```
M-x MINOR-MODE-NAME
```

#### Using a key binding

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<KEY>") #'MINOR-MODE-NAME)
```

#### Using elisp (non-interactively)

```el
(MINOR-MODE-NAME 'toggle)
```

---

### Sources

- [Emacs Manual - Minor Mode Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minor-Mode-Conventions.html)
- [Xah's blog - Turning major.minor mode on/off](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs-tip_mode_on_off_toggle.html)

Comment: I've run into some modes where you have to pass t or nil instead of numbers.

Comment: @JosephGarvin It might be worthwhile to find out which those modes are.. and may be file a bug report to fix that inconsistency if in fact they are defined as minor modes?

Comment: The answer is very abstract. I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor What's the minor mode you're trying to control that led you to this answer?

Comment: The one in the question. (`global-auto-revert-mode`)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the issue. I have `(MINOR-MODE-NAME)` in my answer. Looks like it's not obvious .. I'll add a note to replace `MINOR-MODE-NAME` with the actual minor mode name.

Answer (score 1):

auto-revert only works for buffers which are not modified.  So at least for the "trying to save and getting the file changed on disk prompt" the behavior you describe is normal.

Comment: I opened the same file simultaneously in an emacs 25.0 instance and emacs 24.4 instance (both with `-Q` option) and did `M-x global-auto-revert-mode` in both. From terminal when I echoed some string ( `echo 1234 >> somefile.txt`) to that file, only the emacs 24.4 buffer auto-reverted.

Comment: Then please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Done! [**bug # 20441**](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20441)

Comment: The "bug" got resolved by itself.. was probably an issue with glib on my system.