# Toggle abbrev-mode using keyboard

Tags: elisp, abbrev

I would like to be able to toggle abbrev-mode on and off with ease. Of course I could use

```
M-x abbrev-mode
```

But I would like to set this to some keyboard shortcut. To this end I've added the following to my .emacs file

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") (lambda () (interactive) (abbrev-mode nil)))
```

But this doesn't have the desired effect. How do I enable this functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [global-auto-revert-mode doesn't seem to work?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/global-auto-revert-mode-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: There is a difference between calling a function in a interactive command, and calling a function interactively. Like abo-abo specified, you just need to remove the wrapper lambda, but you could also use `call-interactively` in your lambda to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the wrapper:

```cl
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'abbrev-mode)
```