# How to automatically highlight all the words same with selection just like Notepad++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting

For example when I select a word I want the same words to be automatically highlighted just like it in Notepad++:

When I select the word "install" in Notepad++ (all other "install" are highlighted"):

[image]

I'm using `spacemacs`. I tried the package `auto-highlight-symbol` and also the package `highlight-symbol`. Set mode to 1 in `.spacemacs`. But when I select a word no other same words highlighted:

Comment: auto-highlight-symbol work for me, but I'm not sure about spacemacs. Is the face (color) too close to background?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say "syntaxes": do you mean particular words or symbols?  Please also clarify what you mean by "none of them are working."  Edit you post to explain what, exactly, you did, what you expected, and what happened instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use package [highlight-symbol](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/).

```lisp
(use-package highlight-symbol
  :ensure t
  :init
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'highlight-symbol-mode))
```

Comment: This is nice and neat and in order to also easily navigate through highlighted you may look here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12530/enable-highlighting-symbols-in-prog-mode

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple packages that do this:

- [auto-highlight-symbol](https://github.com/jcs-elpa/auto-highlight-symbol)
- [highlight-symbol](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el)
- [idle-highlight](https://github.com/nonsequitur/idle-highlight-mode)

They all perform the basics well enough.

Although `idle-highlight` was the only package that worked well on large buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any external package. Take a look at the functions `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` and `isearch-forward-symbol`.

To find out if they're bound to a key on Spacemacs, evaluate `(where-is 'isearch-forward-symbol)`.

Comment: Can this be done without moving the cursor?

Comment: @ideasman42 yes.